# how to change the NLS_LANGUAGE and other parameters in oracle

Tags: oracle

i have NLS_LANGUAGE American, I want to change to ITALIAN, The database is oracle 11g.

I am trying the following

```
ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET ITALIAN
```

but this gives error.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you like to modify the NLS_LANGUAGE of the entire database, just on your local session.

Run `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE="ITALIAN";`

Do you like to modify the NLS_LANGUAGE or the CHARACTER Set? These are two completely different things.

Comment: I am importing a dump and that give me error: IMP-00038

Comment: i have the following error: IMP-00038 Could not convert to environment character set's handle

Comment: This is not stated in your question, please edit your question again with the necessary information, also if you use imp or impdb

Answer (score 2):

The default value of NLS_LANGUAGE may be operating system-specific. You can alter the NLS_LANGUAGE parameter by changing the value in the initialization file and then restarting the instance. 
This setting is in the init.ora or spfile.ora.

If you just want to change your session info for example to change the date format, but without changing server messages you can use alter session as follows:

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE=Italian;
SQL> SELECT ename, hiredate, ROUND(sal/12,2) sal FROM emp;
ENAME     HIREDATE    SAL
-----     --------    ---
Clark     09-Dic-88   4195.83
Miller    23-Mar-87   4366.67
Strauß    01-Apr-95   3795.87

SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE=German;
SQL> SELECT ename, hiredate, ROUND(sal/12,2) sal FROM emp;
ENAME     HIREDATE    SAL
-----     --------    ---
Clark     09-DEZ-88   4195.83
Miller    23-MÄR-87   4366.67
Strauß    01-APR-95   3795.87
```

Comment: could not found init.ora and spfile.ora

Comment: For modification of init.ora or spfile.ora please ask your DBA, he will support you. In case you don't know one of these files I recommoment to you better not to touch them - you may destroy your DB.

Answer (score 0):

Run at host level, setting env variables `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`

```
export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8
```